# how display retrieve data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**my model code**

```
public function retrivecat()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row->catname;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

My controller code

```
function addPost()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data = array(
        'pageTitle' => 'ارسال مطلب',
        'username' => $username
    );
    $this->load->model('category');
    $data = $this->category->retrivecat();
    $this->load->view('dashboard/post',$data);
}
```

my view code :

```
print_r($data);
exit();
```

but, this is not worked and display :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: dashboard/post.php
>
> Line Number: 72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing variables into the view you must do this:

```
 function addPost()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data = array(
        'pageTitle' => 'ارسال مطلب',
        'username' => $username
    );
    $this->load->model('category');
    $data['variable'] = $this->category->retrivecat();
    $this->load->view('dashboard/post',$data);
}
```

Then in the view do `print_r($variable);`